# Velocity Can't find Formatter class

Tags: logging, velocity, polarion

I am making use of Velocity Template Engine (Velocity 1.4) to set up a mailing system.

Initialising Velocity is throwing below error:

2022-12-19 04:52:11,269 [pool-6-thread-1] WARN   - PANIC : Velocity cannot find any of the specified or default logging systems in the classpath, or the classpath doesn't contain the necessary classes to support them. Please consult the documentation regarding logging. Exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log/format/Formatter
2022-12-19 04:52:11,269 [pool-6-thread-1] WARN   - Exception in thread "pool-6-thread-1"
2022-12-19 04:52:11,269 [pool-6-thread-1] WARN   - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log/format/Formatter
2022-12-19 04:52:11,269 [pool-6-thread-1] WARN   - at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.LogManager.createLogSystem(LogManager.java:162)
2022-12-19 04:52:11,269 [pool-6-thread-1] WARN   - at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.initializeLogger(RuntimeInstance.java:553)
2022-12-19 04:52:11,269 [pool-6-thread-1] WARN   - at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:226)
2022-12-19 04:52:11,269 [pool-6-thread-1] WARN   - at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:461)
2022-12-19 04:52:11,269 [pool-6-thread-1] WARN   - at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.init(VelocityEngine.java:106)
2022-12-19 04:52:11,269 [pool-6-thread-1] WARN   - at com.example.mail.Renderer.setVelocityEngine(Renderer.java:32)
2022-12-19 04:52:11,269 [pool-6-thread-1] WARN   - at com.example.mail.Renderer.getTemplate(Renderer.java:42)
2022-12-19 04:52:11,269 [pool-6-thread-1] WARN   - at com.example.polarion.Util.sendMailForTrigger(Util.java:733)
2022-12-19 04:52:11,269 [pool-6-thread-1] WARN   - at com.example.a3.servlet.async.PushEventProcessor.process(PushEventProcessor.java:232)
2022-12-19 04:52:11,269 [pool-6-thread-1] WARN   - at com.example.a3.servlet.async.PushEventProcessorThread.run(PushEventProcessorThread.java:52)
2022-12-19 04:52:11,269 [pool-6-thread-1] WARN   - at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
2022-12-19 04:52:11,269 [pool-6-thread-1] WARN   - at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)

[velocity engine properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtGw3.png)

I have tried adding logkit.jar to classpath.

Comment: Are you joking? Velocity 1.4 was released in 2007, more than 15 years ago...

Comment: Legacy Project. Not joking

Answer (score 0):

Even if the `org.apache.format.Formatter` class is in the classpath, the JVM may be unable to load it if there is a missing dependency for logkit.

If this is the case, then the exception you get will have a root cause, and you can loop like this in your catch clause:

```
try {
  /// do the work
} catch (Exception e) {
  while (e != null) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    e = e.getCause();
  }
}
```

For the record, here are all Velocity 1.4 dependencies (which aren't probably all needed in your case):

- commons-collections 2.0
- logkit 1.0.1
- servlet-api 2.3
- jdom b10
- oro 2.0.6
- log4j & log4j-core 1.1.3
- werken-xpath 0.9.4
- xml-apis 2.0.2
- jdbc 2.0

All those dependencies are provided in the `velocity-1.4.zip` that you can download from [this page](https://archive.apache.org/dist/velocity/engine/1.4/).